# Differentiating between hormones triggered on specific types of happiness?

Tags: endocrinology, dopamine

Achievement:- Dopamine

Applause:- Seratonin

Discovering something new:-?

Remembering something after a long time/struggle:-?

Nostalgia:-?

Lust ;-Testosterone/Estrogen

Romantic Love:- Dopamine?

Attachment:- Oxytocin or Vasopressin?

Cuddling pets/babies:- Oxytocin or Vasopressin?

Motherhood:- Oxytocin & Vasopressin?

Also, is happiness in all cases equal? I mean that is happiness just differing in magnitude rather than type when comparing different activities? For eg, happiness on discovering something new is the same exact as happiness on kissing your crush, just differing magnitude and triggered by a different hormone?

Like in video games, we have damage versus status effect (losing hitpoints versus getting paralyzed or stunned), is that a better analogy to the various kinds of happiness or is it more like fire damage versus ice damage,

Comment: My apologies, but I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding your question. Can you try to edit it to focus more precisely on a specific aspect of what you are interested in?

Comment: which hormone is triggered when

Comment: How about Noradrenalin,  Melatonin, Tyramin & Tryptamin ? Not to forget the countermechanic, enzymatic groups that catalyze the oxidation of monoamines via monoamine-oxidases..

Comment: I think you need to narrow your question a bit, as right now it could be answered with several full textbooks. That said, a simple answer is that there is no such thing as a "happiness hormone" (despite some pop sci articles attributing this to one hormone or another), and all that you've listed are associated with far more than the pairings you've written here. You can give someone heroin and they experience happiness, but we don't call heroin a happiness drug.